# How to make the image corresponding to a digit be displayed instead of numbers when pressing buttons?

Tags: reactjs

At the moment, I have two buttons, the prev button decreases the number by 1, and the next button increases by 1.
I need to somehow make that instead of the number to the right of the buttons, or somewhere on the page, the images that I have in the array are displayed:
image banana = number 1
watermelon = number 2
strawberries = number 3

That is, how it should be:

There are buttons on the page and on the right the picture is a banana so in state I set the value to 1 and the number one corresponds to the number 1, when I pressed the next button the watermelon appeared (number 2), pressed another next the strawberry was displayed and so on in a circle. If the number is greater than 3, a picture is displayed under the number 1, and if it is less than 1 then under the number 3.

What needs to be added / changed in my code to implement this?
P.S. Maybe it was better to add images to state and not to the items variable?

Here is my source code:

```
const items = [
    { img: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3117087049/697e0334a13361c6ab68ce00aefefa4f.jpeg" },
    { img: "http://vkclub.su/_data/gifts/134.jpg" },
    { img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTBIqdLHvhxu4LAxudRrH2OoJSctYh9pw3NyziKUwbpp77tsOvu" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: 1,
  }

  plus = () => {
    this.setState({
      image: this.state.image + 1,
    });
  }

  minus = () => {
      this.setState({
      image: this.state.image - 1,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div><button onClick={this.minus}>Prev</button>
        <button onClick={this.plus}>Next</button>
        {this.state.image}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and in the sandbox:
https://jsfiddle.net/51jevc4y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just correctly updating state

```
plus = () => {
    this.setState({
      image: (this.state.image + 1)%items.length,
    });
  }

  minus = () => {
      this.setState({
      image: (this.state.image - 1+items.length)%items.length,
    });
  }
```

and in render method to show images you have to use `img` tag

```
<img src={items[this.state.image].img}/> //Assuming your image links are in this format items=[{img:'link1'},{img:'link2'},...] as it is used in your given fiddle link.
```

Here is an working [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wzmy4619/)